# Error when i create a new project with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I install Eclipse , when i try to create a new project i have this errors !

[image]

I install all libraries Exras . I added support library ? i tired with a lot of solution in SO ... But u have always a some errors

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75 Android AAPT Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Android\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar' AppTest     Build path  Build Path Problem

Comment: Are you install android 5 sdk ?

Comment: uninstall Eclipse, install Android Studio. http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: Maybe.You must use same support your project and other lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to `File -> Import -> (Android Package) Existing Android Code Into Workspace -> Next -> (find folder) your_adt_location -> skd -> extras -> android -> v7 -> appcompact -> finish`, and then add it as a library by `Right click -> properties -> Adnroid tab -> library window(there use add and choose it, remove other version if it exists there)` to your project and rebuild it

Comment: Thanks but Eclipse add appcompat_v7 automatically

Comment: But you can say from an error that it has been add wrong, maybe you should do it manually, or, maybe you should just rebuild your workspace and also check Properties -> JavaBuildPath -> Libraries tab, maybe there is a .jar instance of this library that should be removed

Comment: Where i can find skd -> extras -> android -> v7 -> appcompact ?

Comment: it shpuld be in your_adt_path, mine is called adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702, if you're using adt, it's folder where eclipse if located, or you can just Window->Preferences->Android to see where sdk located

Comment: dou you have any success yet?

Answer (score 1):

sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

It is an error of missing android-support-v7-appcompat.jar file in your libs folder. add it from your sdk folder's .

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Android SDK Manager > Extras > Android Support Library** and install it